# Как согласовать глагол с названием команды?

Tags: грамматика, согласование

— Из «Ольборга» вас переманило «Торпедо», где вы забили всего восемь голов за три года.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь у вас правильно: ***...вас переманило «Торпедо»...***

Имя собственное "Торпедо" имеет четко определяемый средний род. Поэтому сказуемое согласуется в грамматическом роде с подлежащим как оно есть.

В тех же случаях, когда определение рода имени собственного (или видового слова) затруднительно, согласование может осуществляться (императивно или как вариант) по родовому слову, в спорте это обычно "клуб": *ЦСКА обыграл "Химки"*, *"Чеховские медведи"* вышли в финал" и  *"Чеховские медведи"* (клуб) вышел в финал".

Подробнее смотрите здесь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm (в частности -  §188, п. 5)

(+)
По поводу Ушакова и проч.

Во-первых, "Торпедо"  создавалось как спортивное **общество**, а не клуб или "команда". Во-вторых, у Ушакова ничего не сказано про спортивное значение. И в-третьих, с момента основания общества оно приобрело средний род. Это естественно, слово имеет все признаки среднего рода, а что там было при царе Горохе да в другом значении - "не суть важно".

Доказательство - см. кино "Вратарь". 1938 г.
https://kino-ussr.ru/241-vratar-1936.html

*"Торпедо" перешло на половину противника...* (на 41:20)

(++) И вот еще - со "Справки"

> ```
>   Вопрос № 282759      
>   
>
> Здравствуйте!
>
> "Тосно забило быстрый гол."
>
> "Город Тосно - мужской род.
> Река Тосна - женский род.
> Клуб Тосно - мужской род.
> Команда Тосно - женский род.
> А средний откуда?"
>
> Так какого рода Тосно?
> ```
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> На согласование по среднему роду влияет внешний облик этого слова (оно
> несклоняемое, оканчивается на гласный, ср.: «Динамо» забило,
> ***«Торпедо» вылетело***). Да и с родовой принадлежностью названия города
> тоже не всё однозначно: словарь Е. А. Левашова «Географические
> названия» указывает, что название города Тосно может употребляться как
> существительное мужского и среднего рода, а «Грамматический словарь
> русского языка» А. А. Зализняка фиксирует Тосно как существительное
> только среднего рода.
>
> Таким образом, можно говорить о допустимости согласования и по мужскому
> роду (влияние родовых слов город, футбольный клуб), и по
> среднему роду (влияние внешнего фонетического облика названия).

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=+282759

(+++)

> Какое горе заставило людей перейти так быстро в привычном слове на
> другой род?

Я думаю, дело не в фильме. Хотя про фильм есть небольшая информация. У Кассиля, в литературном первоисточнике ("Вратарь республики") команда называлась "Магнето" - ср. рода. В первоначальном варианте сценария - тоже. Переименовали уже после начала работы над фильмом - в честь реальной команды. Возможно, конечно, что просто недоправили. Но скорее всего все проще. Это торпедо в значении автомобиля на самом деле не могло получить широкого распространения. Его мало кто знал.

А вот став спортобществом, слово пошло в народ. И его быстро постигла та же судьба, что и "пальто" с "метро" - оба эти слова первоначально фиксировались в языке как слова мужского рода.

> Но Метро сверкнул перилами дубовыми...

(Утесов)

> В повестях и романах, написанных около середины XIX века или
> несколько раньше, слово это печаталось французскими буквами:
>
> «Он надел свой модный paletot».
>
> «Его синий paletot был в пыли».
>
> По-французски paletot — мужского рода, и даже тогда, когда это слово
> стало печататься русскими буквами, оно еще лет восемь или десять
> сохраняло мужской род и у нас. В тогдашних книгах мы могли прочитать:
>
> «Этот красивый палето».
>
> «Он распахнул свой осенний палето».
>
> У Герцена в «Былом и думах» — теплый пальто.

(Чуковский "Живой как жизнь")

Но это продолжалось очень недолго.

Comment: Спасибо. Хорошо, что всё стало на свои места.

Comment: Про фильм "Вратарь" интересно. В те времена автомобиль типа "торпедо" был в моде, слово частенько употребляется в книгах (в мужском роде) — вероятно, было на слуху. Какое горе заставило людей перейти так быстро в привычном слове на другой род? Ладно бы болельщиков в глубинке можно было заподозрить, что по неграмотности они не слышали такого слова, но в фильме?

Comment: @grizzly отвечаю в тексте.

Answer (score 2):

Да, действительно, такое [интервью](https://sport.rambler.ru/other/40732999-lobanovskiy-oral-vy-nas-ubit-hotite-iz-estonii-v-london-k-vengeru-torpedo-i-kitay/?updated) есть.

1. Для того чтобы понять, глагол какой формы надо использовать, нужно определить род слова "торпедо".

В словаре Ушакова:
[**торпе́до**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1056090), нескл., **муж.** (спец.). То же, что торпеда во 2 знач.

В [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE) также утверждается, что слово "торпедо" мужского рода.
В современных словарях слова нет, отсутствует оно и в "Словаре русского языка" 1961 года (том четвертый).
Московский футбольный клуб ["Торпедо"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE_(%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1,_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0)) получил это название в 1936 году (это время появления словаря Ушакова [1935—1940]), поэтому думаю, что правильно было бы использовать слово в мужском роде: *переманил "Торпедо"*.
Повсеместное употребление слова в среднем роде, возможно, происходит из-за того, что похожее слово [динамо](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE) (это также и название другого футбольного клуба [1923]) имеет средний род.

*Капитан сборной КР по футболу Валерий Кичин покинул **московский "Торпедо".**

**Владимирский «Торпедо»** сыграл вничью с питерской командой.*

2. Имена собственные (клички животных, географические наименования, названия газет, журналов, клубов и т. д.) являются приложениями, и сказуемое согласуется с нарицательным существительным, например: ***Журнал** «Литературное наследство» **опубликовал** новые материалы о творчестве М. Булгакова.*

[§ 185. Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим, имеющим при себе приложение](http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliii-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-podlezhashchim/ss-185-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-podlezhashchim-imeyushchim-pri-sebe-prilozhenie)

Правильно:
клуб "Торпедо" выиграл; команда "Торпедо" участвовала.

Comment: Ответ поддержал, но я с ним не согласен :)

Comment: Я тоже не согласен. Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь согласование (при отсутствии приложения) обычно делается в **среднем роде**, поэтому запись можно считать верной.

Информацию можно проверить на сайте клуба https://www.torpedo.ru/club/history/

Например: В советский период **«Торпедо» являлось** постоянным участником элитной лиги союзных чемпионатов. **Московское** "Торпедо" – это отдельная веха отечественного футбола.

https://www.euro-football.ru/team/torpedo_moskva/history#ixzz6SNClXN1N

Также: https://www.euro-football.ru/team/torpedo_moskva/history

Согласование в мужском роде встречается в СМИ, но скорее оно относится к слову "клуб". Вряд ли здесь учитывается, что когда-то слово являлось существительным мужского рода. В современном языке название относят к среднему роду по его грамматической форме.

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ 2 (улучшенная версия)**

Умом Россию не понять,

Аршином общим не измерить:

У ней особенная стать —

В Россию можно только верить.

Оригинал этого короткого стихотворения Тютчева  был записан на клочке бумаги под каким-то впечатлением, и **каждый  понимает это высказывание по-своему**. Да, мы особенные, **иррациональные, разумом непостижимые**. Потому что ум узок, прямолинеен, ищет во всем причинно-следственную связь, – и когда не находит, то признает свое бессилие. **Мы – многомерные, поэтому общий аршин не для нас.**

Об этом я думаю, когда смотрю на три данных ответа и их оценку. Вот лучший ответ (2 голоса), вот ответ неправильный, но все равно правильный (1 голос). И их качественная оценка: (1) Хорошо, что всё стало на свои места. (2) Ответ поддержал, но я с ним не согласен.

А мой ответ  —  **бесполезный,** а скорее всего, вообще невидимый, написан бесцветными чернилами. **Нет в нем чувства**, нужного людям.

Но разум не хочет этого понимать и предлагает  **улучшенную версию ответа**. Ему (разуму)  хочется **совершенства** (хотя оно тоже недостижимо): понятного содержания и краткой формы, непротиворечивости и иинформативности.

**Вопрос**: Как согласовать глагол с названием команды?

— Из «Ольборга» вас переманило «Торпедо», где вы забили всего восемь голов за три года.

**Ответ:** Согласование в среднем роде – это правильное согласование.

**Пояснение**

Само название  относят к среднему роду по его грамматической форме (окончание на О/Е в начальной форме).

Это тот  вариант, который мы видим **на сайтах клуба**, например:
Например: В советский период **«Торпедо» являлось** постоянным участником элитной лиги союзных чемпионатов. **Московское "Торпедо"** – это отдельная веха отечественного футбола.

https://www.torpedo.ru/club/history/
https://www.euro-football.ru/team/torpedo_moskva/history#ixzz6SNClXN1N

**Примечания**

1. Согласование **в мужском роде** может встретиться в СМИ, но скорее оно относится к слову "клуб".  Однако по правилам при отсутствии приложения такое согласование **не является корректным.** Возможные варианты: переманило «Торпедо»,  переманила команда «Торпедо», переманил клуб «Торпедо».
2. Вряд ли здесь учитывается мужской род **устаревшего** существительного ***торпедо*** (от лат. torpedo) – тип спортивного автомобиля со складной крышей первой трети XX века. [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/торпедо](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE)